# Return zero value for all the month in series with count zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, common-table-expression

This is my query:

```
SELECT STAFF.stf_first_name + '' + STAFF.stf_last_name As Name,
       DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As Month,
       SUM(case when RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration > 0
                then (RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration/15) else 0 end) As ServiceDeliveryTime,
       MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As MonthNumber 
FROM RES_HAB_DATA
  JOIN RES_HAB ON RES_HAB_DATA.reshab_id = RES_HAB.reshab_id
  JOIN STAFF ON RES_HAB_DATA.staff_id = STAFF.stf_id
WHERE RES_HAB.serv_id = 30
  AND RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date >= '1/1/2015'
GROUP BY STAFF.stf_last_name,
         STAFF.stf_first_name,
         DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date),
         MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date)
ORDER BY MonthNumber
```

Which produces result set as:

```
Name                         Month      ServiceDeliveryTime     MonthNumber
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mb                           January             52                 1
MikeCasey                    January             10                 1
MikeCasey                    February            4                  2
PrecisionCareSupport         February            0                  2
MikeCasey                    March               4                  3
PrecisionCareSupport         March               0                  3
MikeCasey                    April               8                  4
PrecisionCareSupport         April               0                  4
MikeCasey                    May                 16                 5
MikeCasey                    July                4                  7
PrecisionCareSupport         July                1                  7
PrecisionCareSupport         August              0                  8
MikeCasey                    September           10                 9
MikeCasey                    October             12                 10
```

I am generating a chart and would like to generate series for that chart but the series should be formed in a way that each series label must have all the tick values(zero if missing respective month). In Simple words,I want resultset as:

```
Name                         Month      ServiceDeliveryTime     MonthNumber
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mb                           January             52                 1
mb                           February            0                  2
mb                           March               0                  3
mb                           April               0                  4
-                              -                 0                  5
```

Upto December then series will continue for Client MikeCasey upto December and so on...for all the series Labels.If any of the tick is missing for that client there will be value zero for that month.

How Can I produce this result set ? I want some uniform solution because there can be number of such queries for different charts.

Comment: Pleasa tag dbms product used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Do you have a month help table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Shaw, try this

```
;WITH 
(SELECT STAFF.stf_first_name + '' + STAFF.stf_last_name As Name,
       DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As Month,
       SUM(case when RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration > 0
            then (RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration/15) else 0 end) As ServiceDeliveryTime,
       MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As MonthNumber 
 FROM RES_HAB_DATA
  JOIN RES_HAB ON RES_HAB_DATA.reshab_id = RES_HAB.reshab_id
  JOIN STAFF ON RES_HAB_DATA.staff_id = STAFF.stf_id
WHERE RES_HAB.serv_id = 30
    AND RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date >= '1/1/2015'
GROUP BY STAFF.stf_last_name,
     STAFF.stf_first_name,
     DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date),
     MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date)
) AS mytable
SELECT 
    myTableName.Name
    ,mytableMonth.Month
    ,ISNULL(mytable.ServiceDeliveryTime,0)
    ,mutableMonth.MonthNumber
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Name from mytable) mytableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Month,MonthNumber FROM mytable) mytableMonth
    LEFT INNER JOIN mytable ON mytableName.Name = mytable.Name AND mytableMonth.Month = mytable.Month AND mytableMonthNumber = mytable.MonthNumber
ORDER BY mytableName.Name, mytableMonth.MonthNumber
```

I have taken all distinct months and names from your data and done a cross join.

Comment: Thanks a lot adish..With some minor changes I was able to get the desired output. Cheers.

Comment: good to know. If suitable, please mark this as selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH mytable(Name,Month,ServiceDeliveryTime,MonthNumber) AS
(
SELECT STAFF.stf_first_name + '' + STAFF.stf_last_name As Name,
   DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As Month,
   SUM(case when RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration > 0
        then (RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_duration/15) else 0 end) As ServiceDeliveryTime,
   MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date) As MonthNumber 
 FROM RES_HAB_DATA
JOIN RES_HAB ON RES_HAB_DATA.reshab_id = RES_HAB.reshab_id
JOIN STAFF ON RES_HAB_DATA.staff_id = STAFF.stf_id
WHERE RES_HAB.serv_id = 30
AND RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date >= '1/1/2015'
GROUP BY STAFF.stf_last_name,
 STAFF.stf_first_name,
 DATENAME(month,RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date),
 MONTH(RES_HAB_DATA.reshabdata_data_date)
) 
SELECT 
myTableName.Name
,mytableMonth.Month_Name
,ISNULL(mytable.ServiceDeliveryTime,0) as ServiceDeliveryTime
,mytableMonth.id
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name from mytable) mytableName
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Month_Name,id FROM MyMonths)  mytableMonth
LEFT JOIN mytable ON mytableName.Name = mytable.Name AND mytableMonth.Month_Name = mytable.Month AND mytable.MonthNumber = mytable.MonthNumber
ORDER BY mytableName.Name, mytableMonth.id
```

MyMonths table is already created table with id as MonthNumber and Month_Name as Month.
Cheers!